# store form details within phonegap and send when online

Tags: php, ios, forms, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am looking into building an app for internal distribution using phonegap on iOS.

The app will include a form which will send an email out. There is however often a point when the form needs to be used when the user isn't connected to the Internet.

I am trying to find a way to save the form data offline and then submit this as soon as there is a connection. The form will be used during sales pitches so there will be multiple submissions that have to be sent individually.

Answer (score 0):

Save the form to local storage using this plugin https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage then set a watcher for internet connection to send anything stored in local to the server. Remove the entry from local storage when the upload is confirmed in the success function. See... https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information

Comment: What if the application is minimized or swiped/killed? Does phonegap run javascript code? I was not able to find any info for the same in cordova-plugin-network-information, can you verify with a link or something that it will post my data even if the application is minimised/killed

Comment: If there is no internet at the time of sending you will need to retry when a connection is established. If you saved the form data as an object in javascript you would lose the data if the app is killed by the user or by iOS in the background. To persist the data between instances of the app where the initial instance is killed you can use local storage which persists the data. When relaunching you can then check to see if there are any entries in local storage and send if there is a connection.